# How do I find the image of a function on an open interval?

Tags: limits, functions

Say $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and I want to find the image of $f$ on the open interval $(0,1)$. As $x$ approaches $0$, $f(x)$ goes to $\infty$, and as $x$ approaches $1$, $f(x)$ goes to $1$. Is the image set $(1, \infty)$, or is it $[1, \infty$), or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image of a function is the set of all values that the function attains. You say that $f$ approaches infinity as $x$ approaches $0$, and $f$ approaches $1$ as $x$ approaches $1$. These are both true, but $f$ never actually attains those values; they are $\textit{limits}$ not function values. Of course $f(1) = 1$, but $1 \notin (0,1)$. In order for $y \in$ Image$(f)$, there needs to be an $x$-value in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x) = y$.